# How to submit form on button click and then run AJAX call assigned to the same button

Tags: python, ajax, django

I am wrtitng a simple Airbnb scraper. When the user submits a form with city name filled in, he will get a table with prices and links rendered by AJAX on the same page.

The form is in my "index.html":

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input id="create_table" type="submit" value="View results" />
</form>
<div id="table">Place for table</div>
```

I am using two views: "index" and "results". "Index" is just for collecting the city name and passing it to the "results" (which is called by AJAX, see below):

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RoomForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            city = form.cleaned_data['city'].title()
            request.session['city'] = city
    else:
        form = RoomForm() 

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'javascript/index.html', context)

def results(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        city = request.session.get('city')
        url = 'https://www.airbnb.pl/s/' + str(city) +'
        # "results" scraping code continues...
```

I need to pass the `city` variable from "index" to "results", hence the `request.session` part.

However I think the variable never gets assigned because the following `.load` AJAX call (the other call to API is irrelevant to the example)

```
function create_table() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/api/data/",
        success: function(data){
            $('#table').load('http://127.0.0.1:8000/results', function(){
              $('#go_back').remove();
            });
        },
        error: function(error_data){
            console.log("errorrr")
            console.log(error_data)
        }
    })
}
document.getElementById("create_table").onclick = function() {
    create_table();
    return false;
```

, which is assigned to the same submit button, is launched first and "results" view is loaded, skipping the form submit, hence the variable gets passed as `None`.

The end result looks like this (notice the "None" in link text instead of "Barcelona"):

[image]

How do I work around this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried assigning the javascript code to an onsubmit attribute

```
<form onsubmit="return create_table()" action="" method="post>
```

Just ensure that it returns a default empty state when the data is not required.